# Hostname issue on server

Tags: linux, hosting, web-hosting

Email from WHM/CPANEL

```
Your hostname (HOSTIT) could not be resolved to an IP address.
This means that /etc/hosts is not set up correctly, and/or there is
no dns entry for HOSTIT. Please be sure that the contents of
/etc/hosts are configured correctly, and also that there is a
correct 'A' entry for the domain in the zone file.

Some or all of these problems can be caused by /etc/resolv.conf
being setup incorrectly. Please check that file if you believe
everything else is correct.

You may be able to automatically correct this problem by using the
'Add an A entry for your hostname' option under 'Dns Functions' in
your Web Host Manager.
```

HOSTS FILE:

```
cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1               localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1             localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
18.14.16.26           HOSTIT HOSTIT.co sqwb1 sqwb1.HOSTIT.co
```

AND DNS:
I can ping both HOSTIT.co and sqwb1.HOSTIT.co and they go to the correct IP

What could be causing this?

Comment: can you also 'ping HOSTIT'?  Your hosts file line works fine on my server; I suspect WHM may not be handling the non-qualified domain name (single word with no dot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a FQDN as your hostname with CPanel:

Your hostname is the name by which your physical web server will be known across the Internet. It is important to choose a hostname that will not be used for a cPanel account, is socially acceptable (as it will appear in mail headers), and is a fully qualified domain name (FQDN — this will contain 2 dots, ‘.’)
...
FQDNs must also be written in lowercase letters. These requirements can be reviewed under the Instructions heading, on the main Hostname page.

source: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/HOstname